# Avoid duplicate entries using full JOIN with SUM and GROUP BY

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB for the database and have the following condition in which I have to avoid duplicate entries while joining 2 tables.

Table1

```
HMEXPENSE
+--------+---------------+-------------+
| USERID | EXPENSEAMOUNT | EXPENSEDATE |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
|      a |      100      | 2018-10-10  |
|      a |      200      | 2018-10-11  |
|      a |      100      | 2018-10-11  |
|      a |      200      | 2018-10-13  |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

Table2

```
HMINCOME
+--------+---------------+-------------+
| USERID | EXPENSEAMOUNT | EXPENSEDATE |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
|      a |      200      | 2018-10-10  |
|      a |      100      | 2018-10-11  |
|      a |      200      | 2018-10-11  |
|      a |      100      | 2018-10-12  |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

The current query which gives me the duplicate entries is as follows

```
SELECT e.expenseDate ,i.incomeDate , SUM(e.expenseAmount), SUM(i.incomeAmount)
FROM HMINCOME i FULL JOIN HMEXPENSE e on i.incomeDate = e.expenseDate 
GROUP BY i.incomeDate,e.expenseDate, i.incomeAmount, e.expenseAmount
```

OUTPUT

```
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
| EXPENSEDATE | INCOMEDATE |   C3  |   C4  |
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
|  2018-10-10 | 2018-10-10 | 100.0 | 200.0 |
|  2018-10-11 | 2018-10-11 | 200.0 | 100.0 |
|  2018-10-11 | 2018-10-11 | 100.0 | 100.0 |
|  2018-10-11 | 2018-10-11 | 200.0 | 200.0 |
|  2018-10-11 | 2018-10-11 | 100.0 | 200.0 |
|   <null>    | 2018-10-12 | <null>| 100.0 |
|  2018-10-13 |   <null>   | 200.0 | <null>|
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

And if I use this above-mentioned query to get the  actual output which is required in my actual scenario is as follows

```
SELECT e.expenseDate, i.incomeDate , SUM(e.expenseAmount),SUM(i.incomeAmount)
FROM HMINCOME i FULL JOIN HMEXPENSE e on i.incomeDate = e.expenseDate 
GROUP BY i.incomeDate,e.expenseDate
```

OUTPUT

```
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
| EXPENSEDATE | INCOMEDATE |   C3  |   C4  |
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
|  2018-10-10 | 2018-10-10 | 100.0 | 200.0 |
|  2018-10-11 | 2018-10-11 | 600.0 | 600.0 |
|   <null>    | 2018-10-12 | <null>| 100.0 |
|  2018-10-13 |   <null>   | 200.0 | <null>|
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

The requirement is to get the sum of amount for a single day and null entry for the date which is not present in another table.

Expected output is as follows

```
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
| EXPENSEDATE | INCOMEDATE |   C3  |   C4  |
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
|  2018-10-10 | 2018-10-10 | 100.0 | 200.0 |
|  2018-10-11 | 2018-10-11 | 300.0 | 300.0 |
|   <null>    | 2018-10-12 | <null>| 100.0 |
|  2018-10-13 |   <null>   | 200.0 | <null>|
+-------------+------------+-------+-------+
```

C3 and C4 column values are not calculated correctly due to the duplicate entries.

Help...

Comment: Please dont spam tag other RDBMS. Use the specific tag only.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY i.incomeDate, e.expenseDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to solve this uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select dte, sum(incomeamount) as incomeamount, sum(expenseamount) as expenseamount
from ((select incomedate as dte, incomeamount, 0 as expenseamount
       from hmincome
      ) union all
      (select expensedate, 0, expenseAmount
       from hmexpense
      )
     ) ie
group by dte
order by dte;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. Removed "ie" from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Issue here is that you have multiple rows for a date within a table. So, we will need to aggregate them first inside a subquery. Afterwards, it will be then used to do `FULL JOIN`.

Try:

```sql
SELECT 
  e.expenseDate,
  i.incomeDate, 
  e.sumExpenseAmount, 
  i.sumIncomeAmount
FROM 
(SELECT incomeDate, SUM(incomeAmount) sumIncomeAmount
 FROM HMINCOME
 GROUP BY incomeDate) i
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT expenseDate, SUM(expenseAmount) sumExpenseAmount
 FROM HMEXPENSE
 GROUP BY expenseDate) e
  ON i.incomeDate = e.expenseDate
```

Comment: The sub-queries' sum-columns need column aliases. No need for that outer GROUP BY.

Comment: The syntax is supported by HSQLDB